# Cannot push item to array with map() and async-await

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I'm making a discord bot to play youtube video. I'm using this google API to get the video titles from their IDs but the `get_title()` function returns an empty `jsons` array.

I've tried to log the `jsons` array right after the `request()` function and right after the `map()` function but they both return empty arrays. If i `console.log(jsons)` right after `jsons.push(json)` , it does return arrays with titles.

```
const browser = require('https')
var urls = ['https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=AIzaSyC7udvST-lyLpx_gxHBc22kGYhEUOeQz5k&part=snippet&id=QKm4q6kZK7E', 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=AIzaSyC7udvST-lyLpx_gxHBc22kGYhEUOeQz5k&part=snippet&id=ib3fDx75Esw']

function get_title() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var jsons = []
        urls.map(url => {
            browser.request(url, res => {
                let body = ''
                res.on('data', data => {
                    body += data
                })
                res.on('end', () => {
                    var json = JSON.parse(body).items[0].snippet.title
                    jsons.push(json)
                })
            }).end()
        })
        resolve(jsons)

    })
}
async function main() {
    res = await get_title()
    console.log(res)
}
main()
```

I expect the output to be like this

> [ 'Santa Tracker: Making a penguin-proof password','Google Duo: Stay in touch after the Holidays' ]

Comment: You are returning `jsons` before you receive any response for your API calls. The data is pushed to jsons, but the result has already been returned.

Comment: @SachinGupta i've just edited the code. I tried using promise but resolve didnt work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a separate promise for each URL request, and then use `Promise.all`, which will await them all and will gather the responses in an array:

```
function get_title() {
    return Promise.all(urls.map(url => {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            browser.request(url, res => {
                let body = ''
                res.on('data', data => {
                    body += data
                })
                res.on('end', () => {
                    var json = JSON.parse(body).items[0].snippet.title
                    resolve(json)
                })
            }).end()
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `Promise.all()` takes in an array, it helped to consume the map that you have setup. This way you also don't have to track the array:

```
function get_title() {
    return Promise.all(
        urls.map(url => new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            browser.request(url, res => {
                let body = ''
                res.on('data', data => {
                    body += data
                })
                res.on('end', () => {
                    var json = JSON.parse(body).items[0].snippet.title
                    resolve(json)
                })
            }).end()
        }))
    )
}
```